Missing right parenthesis issue after migrating from spring boot 2 to spring boot 3
We have the following where condition query that works fine under springboot 2, but once we migrated to springboot3, it started throwing an exception:
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
the where condition is: and coalesce(:listOfTypes)
The issue is solved when we use: and coalesce(:listOfTypes, null)
But is there any better solutions? is it a bug under spring boot 3?

please give more detail about your issue: snippet code, parameter, context...
